# Disable home button using FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to disable my home button using this:

```
MainActivity(Intent i){
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected void onStop(){
    Intent myIntent = null;
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
}
```

But doesn't work, my develop target is Android 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [this link](https://github.com/shaobin0604/Android-HomeKey-Locker) and I finally managed to lock the HOME button, by adding:

to AndroidManifest.xml All you have to do is to copy HomeKeyLocker.java from shaobin's lib to your project and implement it like in shaobin's example. For more detail please visit the link

This library doesn't support devices with VIRTUAL HOME KEY, such as

Galaxy Nexus
Nexus 4
Nexus 5
Nexus 7